# Get the current view controller in ios

Tags: ios

In my iPod device, I have attached an external device for scanning purpose. There is a scan button for the external device. The delegate methods for the scanner are in the view controller 'ScannerViewController'. Now I am in another view controller called 'NotificationViewController' and click the button present in the external device. When I click the button and the scan is complete, it triggers a method in the ScannerViewController. In that method, I need to get the name of the current view controller that is visible. That is in this case, I need to get the name of the view controller as NotificationViewController.

Comment: This might help [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];

Comment: can you not pass back the active `NotificationViewController` as a property of the delegate? Bit like send of an `IBAction`?

Comment: What kind of container are you using? If you're set up in a UINavigationController, or presenting a modal view controller, you might have an easier time of this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?.

```
NSLog(@"Current View Class: %@", NSStringFromClass(self.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this method

```
NSLog(@"Class name :%@", NSStringFromClass([self.presentedViewController class]);)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using navigation controller, you can try the following:

```
[self.navigationController topViewController];
```

to get the currently visible view.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this

```
+ (UIViewController*) getTopController
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    return topController;
}
```

http://www.iosrocketsurgery.com/2013/07/get-current-viewcontroller-in-ios.html